# Equations in the form f(y,y')=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook, it says that when an equation is given in the form $f(y,y')=0$ we can either solve it by finding $y=g(y')$, making $y'=p$, then $dy=p dx$, so that $y=g(p)$ and differentiating we get $dx=\frac{g'(p)}{p}dp$. Therefore, the general solution of the equation in the parametric form is: $$x=\int\frac{g'(p)}{p}dp+C$$ $$y=g(p)$$

However, if this is not possible and we are able to express the equation in the parametric form: $$y=g(t)$$ $$y'=h(t)$$ therefore, $$dy=g'(t) dt$$ $$dy=h(t) dx$$

and equaling both equations we arrive at $$dx=\frac{g'(t)}{h(t)}dt$$
And the general solution is: $$x=\int\frac{g'(t)}{h(t)}dt+C$$ $$y=g(t)$$

Here is an example of an equation where the second method is needed to solve it: $y^2+(y')^2=1$.
In the textbook they make $y=cos(t)$ and $y'=sin(t)$, so the general solution is: $$x=-t+C$$ $$y=cos(t)$$
What if I decided to make $y=sin(t)$ and $y'=cos(t)$. The general solution would be $$x=t+C$$ $$y=sin(t)$$ How are these two solutions equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The first solution is
$$y = \cos(t) = \cos(-x+C_1) = \cos(\pi/2-(x - C_1 +\pi/2)) = \sin(x - C_1 + \pi/2)$$
and the second solution is
$$y = \sin(t) = \sin(x-C_2)$$
so they are the same solution with $C_2 = C_1 - \pi/2$